# webpack bundle looking for 2.bundle.js in the wrong location

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webpack, vue.js

I am using Vue's aysnc components with the following code:

`Vue.component(
  'async-webpack-example',
  () => import('./my-async-component')
)`

It builds fine and webpack manages to create 2.bundle.js

Unfortunately, when loading the file, it looks for 2.bundle.js in the root (http://example.com/2.bundle.js) and not in http://example.com/js/2.bundle.js where it resides.

Do I need a webpack directive to fix this? If so, what kind of directive do I need? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the answer.

In your webpack.config.js file,

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, './js' ),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: './wp-content/themes/dist/js/'
},
```